# Is "illusionally" an English word?

Tags: word-request, adverbs

I'm writing answers to an assignment of a certain course that I have, and I wrote the following:

> This is possible because in this environment multiple programs of different users can run illusionally at the same time.

What I want to say is that the programs do not actually run at the same time, but there's the illusion that they run at the same time. Yes, this is related to multiprogramming and multitasking for those of you curious :)

Is there an adverb in English which allows me to express that?

Comment: Look into "seemingly" or "apparently."

Comment: If you mean "they appear to run at the same time, but they don't really", then "apparent" or "apparently" is absolutely correct, in this native US English speaker's opinion.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think "apparently" is totally reasonable for this, but I'd be tempted to rephrase it a little to say "can appear to run at the same time." I think "appear" is a bit nicer than "apparently," although either is fine. Unless you do have to use an adverb, in which case never mind! Basically, "apparently" answers the question you asked, but I'd be tempted in another direction, if you can.

Comment: There is the word "illusorily", but it's very uncommon and not likely to be well-understood; just use "apparently or "seemingly".

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you are looking for is

> [illusory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illusory)
>
> This is **illusory** because parts of programs by different users can run very quickly at *almost* the same time to appear contemporaneous or simultaneous.

Answer (score 1):

*Illusionally*, if it were a real word, would mean *in an illusion-ish manner* which is not equivalent to saying *X has the illusion of Y*.

*Illusion* can't really be changed into a word that answers the question *how?* so this doesn't really work.

*Has the illusion of* is the normal way *illusion* is used:

> This is possible because in this environment different users have the illusion of running multiple programs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

True, *illusionally* is not an English word even though *illusional* is.
Here are three suitable options, at different positions within the sentence.

> This is possible because in this environment multiple programs
>   of different users can run **as if** at the same time.
>
> This is possible because in this environment multiple programs
>   of different users can, **in effect**, run at the same time.
>
> This is possible because in this environment multiple programs
>   of different users **effectively** can run at the same time.

Unfortunately, the word *effectively* can be ambiguous.
Placing *effectively* before the word *can*, as in the example,
reduces this ambiguity but does not eliminate it.

> *effectively*
>   [– wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effectively)
>   
>  1. In an efficient or effective manner; with powerful effect.
>   
>  2. Essentially, in effect, for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is "virtually".

[Merriam Webster Online defines it as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtually)

> *almost entirely*; *nearly*; *for all practical purposes*

And a probable usage in your scenario could be:

> This is possible because in this environment multiple programs of different users can run **virtually** at the same time.